# How to switch between multiple chrome tabs in Python selenium web-driver?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

I used a code like below for opening new tabs in chrome.

```
__author__ ="Pranay"
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys    driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Riser20\\PycharmProjects\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://google.co.in")
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://bing.com');")
```

But this code written below for switching the tabs is not working.

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

Please help me with this....

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with opening new tab with CTRL + t, SendKeys method works with no errors but nothing happens in Chrome, I read that it's something related to chromedriver because there is no such behavior on Mozilla Firefox or other browsers.